# Current carrying capabilities of surface mount ICs

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, power-electronics, current-sensor

While putting together a PCB project, I have come across the [ACS724 current sensor](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/files/datasheets/acs724-datasheet.ashx), for measuring AC/DC current in high ranges up to 50 amps. This chip uses hall effect for measurement and is a 'pass-through' type of sensor: No shunt resistor or any other external circuit is used for sensing.

Now here is where it gets amazing: This chip comes in 8-pin SOIC package! For those not familiar, this is very very small. So I started looking for information about the SOIC package standards, but couldn't find anything relating to electrical capabilities, only dimensions. Using the chip involves thermal management but still, I have a hard time believing that a single pin on an SOIC package can handle 25 amps?!?

- Does anyone know where to find electrical data on surface mount packages?
- Does anyone have advice on using such a chip in a circuit, without causing some havoc?

Comment: I agree. But just a thought: the pin is just metal, heatsunk to the PCB, and not connected to anything else inside the IC unlike other ICs, so maybe it's okay?

Comment: Allegro is a respectable maker and I do trus them but it just seems 'outworldly' to put 25a in such a small pin

Comment: I don't know how they do it but if I had to do it, uninformed as I am, I would keep the pins the same (no choice after all) and require them to be well-heat sunk to the PCB but have the conductor considerably wider inside the IC. You get even crazier current ratings for MOSFETs (though I never expect to be able to run at those in practice, unlike the current sensor).

Comment: I've played around in industrial VFD's and the switching semi's weigh up to pounds with their ceramic packages and are rated at 50 amps with 8mm screws for terminals; the whole allegro sensor fits on top of that screw with space to spare... That just clashes with my experience.

Comment: There's a reason I use the CQ-3202 and not the ACS724. For the record, it seems to heat up to like 60-80C at 20A and it has massive terminals. Though...that heat could be coming from accidentally undersizing the trace leading to it. It's hard for me to be sure.

Comment: TY DK, I did not know that chip series, I'm still new at PCB design and have so much to discover with IC's, I'm looking mostly at the collection of JLCPCB to have some assembled.

Comment: You could also use the ACS770 series. They have larger pins for high current connections.

Comment: @Hearth Now those, I trust. But such a disparity in size between two ICs rated for the same current from the same company.

Comment: @DKNguyen I believe 50 A is at the high end of the range of the 724 and the low end of the range of the 770. I think the 770 goes up to 200 A.

Comment: I question is this is an opinion question... But as long as you have a large copper pad of high thickness, it will pull the heat from the SOIC pin without much of an issue. Probably avoid thermals on the pad as well...

Comment: @Hearth  I have been looking at many Ammeter chips and the ACS770 series do indeed seem like an easier choice for a novice project.

Comment: @MadHatter "avoid thermals on the pad" can you briefly explain this phrase for me ; )

Comment: @Simon Thermals are cutouts around a pad that break it out from a copper plane, to reduce the local thermal conductivity making soldering easier. In this case, you do not want them. Most PCB software packages call them thermals.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the pins conduct about as well as AWG 28.  That's a resistance of [0.106 ohms per meter.](https://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/AWG.phtml)

The pins of an [SOIC8](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_outline_integrated_circuit) are approximately 2mm long.

You split the current between two pins, so you halve the resistance.

That'd be something like \$ \frac{0.002m \times 0.213 ohms/m}{2}= 0.000213 ohms\$

At 50A, that's a voltage drop of 0.01065V.

Total power dissipated in one pair of pins is then about 0.53 watts.

The 50A sounds scary, but the total power lost through the pins is fairly small.  You still need to get rid of the heat, though.

That's why datasheet shows that the evaluation board has those great honking copper areas attached to those pins:

[image]

---

The values above aren't necessarily exact.  They are intended to show that even though the current seems outrageously high, the total loss as heat will be much lower than a first glance suggests.

Comment: The pin cross section only works out to be 0.04mm^2. 24 AWG is 0.2mm^2

Comment: The pin cross section is about 0.4mmX0.4mm=0.16mm^2.  That's about AWG 25.   0.106 ohms per meter.

Comment: My bad. It's 0.39 x 0.19mm^2 which is 0.0741mm^2. Not sure where you are getting the second 0.4 from. Two of them gets you in the ballpark of 24AWG I guess.

Comment: My brains are mush.  Too late at night here for this.  I'll try it again.

Comment: Hmmpf.  I mixed Ll and T.

Comment: Thanks JRE so basically I need to make sure the area/pcb can dissipate +-550mW (265in + 265out) and I'm golden!

Comment: About AWG 28. 0.213 ohms per meter.

Comment: @Simon:  Double that.  I flubbed my eyeball estimate of the pin cross section.  I've corrected the answer.  About  0.53W per pin pair.

Comment: OK but I get the Idea I't simple Ohm's law and thermal management. Thanks alot for reassuring me

Comment: The datasheet gives 1.2 mohms resistance for the sense line. So Internally, there's some element that's a bit more restricted than the numbers you calculated with. All the heat from this 1.2 mohm resistor likely has to be sunk out from the IP+/- pins.